# Deserializing a json object property to a String using kotlinx.serialization

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

Given json as follows where the structure of the `payload` object will vary:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "displayName": "Success",
    "payload": {
        "someProperty": "example",
        "someOtherProperty": {
            "someNestedProperty": "example"
        }
    }
}
```

...using `kotlinx.serialization` how can I deserialize this into the following data class, where the value of `payload` should be the raw json string of the payload object.

```
@Serializable
data class Stub(
    val id: Int,
    val displayName: String,
    val payload: String
)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Struggled to find a way of doing this with Serializers, but it was simple enough to implement manually using `JsonElement`.

```
val jsonObject = Json.parseToJsonElement(jsonString).jsonObject
val stub = Stub(
    jsonObject["id"]!!.jsonPrimitive.int,
    jsonObject["displayName"]!!.jsonPrimitive.content,
    jsonObject["payload"]!!.toString()
)
```

Answer (score 11):

There is a way to handle using [JSONTransformingSerializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#json-transformations).  It allows you to transform the json prior to deserialization.  In this case from a jsonElement into a jsonPrimitive (of type String).

First create a transformer as follows:

```
object JsonAsStringSerializer: JsonTransformingSerializer<String>(tSerializer = String.serializer()) {
    override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        return JsonPrimitive(value = element.toString())
    }
}
```

Now apply this transfer to the specific element in your data class by adding...

```
@Serializable(with = JsonAsStringSerializer::class)
```

just above the property you want to transform.  Like this...

```
@Serializable
data class Stub(
    val id: Int,
    val displayName: String,
    @Serializable(with = JsonAsStringSerializer::class)
    val payload: String
)
```

The value of payload will be a string:

```
"{'someProperty': 'example','someOtherProperty': {'someNestedProperty':'example'}"
```

If you are later trying to deserialize this into different models depending on the structure, check out the [JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#content-based-polymorphic-deserialization) feature.

Comment: Could you also post how to do the opposite?  To serialize string property as json object.

Comment: you didn't understand the question, how to deserialize `Stub` class itself from string?

Comment: this is more elegant and idiomatic than the accepted answer